# Blackberry ignore ssl certificate

Tags: blackberry, ssl

My Blackberry application is connecting to a web server via HTTPS.
However, The SSL certificate of the server is invalid.

I would like to know how to ignore the ssl error on my Blackberry application?

I knew with Android you could overwirte the onReceivedSslError method of Android's api to over come this problem. I don't know if there is some way to do it on Blackberry.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IDK... I know on my dad's blackberry this is a very annoying problem, but i haven't found a workaround

Comment: Are you connecting over MDS (the default), or via Carrier TCP or something else?  MDS/BES is sensitive about certs and has had various bugs.

Comment: Buy yourself a valid SSL cert, this is the only option. Has for dev, live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation here http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html#tls, I just add ";EndToEndDesired" to the connection string. And it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

I know of several BlackBerry developers who have expressed concerns over this issue.

While the user can adjust her device security settings to not be notified of SSL certificate issues, there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this programmatically from either inside your application through API, nor through some sort of declaration in the application's .jad file.